# Groups implementable by finite field

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, algebraic-groups, model-theory, finite-fields

I'm interested in finding all groups for which the group operation (and inverse map) may be implemented using finite field arithmetic.

I've done some searching and have come across "algebraic groups", but I don't know enough algebraic geometry to know if this is exactly what I'm after.

If it is, what is known about finding all algebraic groups over finite fields?

Comment: What do you mean by "implementable using finite field arithmetic"? Do you mean that the group is a subset of $F^N$ for some finite field $F$ and that the group operation is given by a polynomial?

Comment: Yes, I think that would include everything I'm interested in. Though I think the group operation should be given by $N$ polynomials in $\mathbb{F}[x_1, \ldots, x_N]$ and likewise for the inverse map.

Comment: I'm adding the model theory tag because model theory provides a useful language to formulate such questions.

Comment: @user135066 What you want is usally called "group of rational points in an algebraic group (over a finite field)". Another useful term is "groups of Lie type". I don't think they've been all classified.

Comment: @DenisNardin I think that Suzuki and Ree groups are considered as groups of Lie type, and are not just defined as groups of points of an algebraic group over a finite field. It involves taking the fixed points by a group automorphism which is not induced by an algebraic automorphism.

Comment: The question remains vague. First, it concerns finite groups if I guess correctly. Every finite group embeds into a symmetric group, which has an obvious linear representation over any field. So each group individually can somewhat be described using finite fields. Of course this is not very useful, but the question is not specific enough to emphasize what more you want to require.

Comment: Good point. My question is computationally motivated, so let me add the following restriction: the group operation should be efficiently computable - say, in poly($\log |G|$) field operations. This should hopefully make question less trivial.

Comment: @user135066 Can you give some examples of "implementations of groups" using finite field arithmetic? And provide more information about the motivation for your question?

Comment: Sure. Easy examples include matrix groups over $\mathbb F_q$, and (multiplicative groups of) finite extensions of $\mathbb F_q$. More interesting examples are elliptic curve groups over $\mathbb F_q$ (and probably other abelian varieties).

The question is motivated by [black-box fields](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/089.pdf). I'm looking for groups where a black-box field element can potentially be embedded and manipulated.

Comment: @DenisNardin, in addition to subsets of $F^N$, one could also allow quotients of them, modulo equivalence relations which take the form $\{p_i(x,y)=0\}$. Then the implementable groups would include projective linear groups also.

Comment: @MattF Just to clarify: I did not mean to imply that groups of Lie type are an alternate term for the groups of rational points, just that it was possibly another relevant search term.